# flink dashboard not showing running jobs from cli

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Windows7, Java 8, Flink 1.5.2. Extracted the tar file, and started bin\start-cluster.bat. I can open the browser URL localhost:8081, it shows all default options.
Developed a small Stream app with Kafka integration, I can receive Kafka message within flink and flink is forwarding it to Kafka (other topic) successfully.
I could test this from Eclipse IDE and from CLI.

Problem: When I run this jar from bin\flink run , the running job's details are not shown on Dashboard, also could not see completed/failed states.

Thanks

Comment: did u find an answer?